# Change the Text of AlertDialog positiveButton after clicking

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have an AlertDialog that has a positive button (OK) and a cancel. When pressing OK, I have a process that should take around 10s to finish (downloading an image from a URL and then showing it on the main page). How can I change the positiveButton text after pressing to be something like "loading"? And also, it should wait until the image is downloaded, so the alert shouldn't disappear.

I tried looking into its functions but didn't see a `setText()` function.

```
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
        builder.setTitle("What's your question?");

        // Set up the input
        final EditText input = new EditText(v.getContext());
        // Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        builder.setView(input);
        input.setText("test test");
        input.setTextSize(15);

        // Set up the buttons
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            m_text = input.getText().toString();
          }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
          }
        });

        builder.show();
      }
    });
```

Comment: Your builder creates the Dialog somehow. Can you use get() or something else to get the dialog? I think you must extract the Dialog into a variable and change the text directly in your dialog-button-click method. Check if you can use a callback which is executed after your action is finished.

Comment: If that is not possible, then switch from using the Builder to create the dialog to using a normal constructor and setters. IMO you should get access to the buttons now.

Comment: How can I do that? I was not able to have the AlertDialog as a var

Comment: If you use intellij: Ctrl +left click on the method show() from builder.show(). A builder is a class that constructs something with the builder pattern. Under the hood, ist uses the normal constructor of the class to be created (AlertDialog).

Comment: Workaround: Close the dialog and display a waiting dialog with a Spinner. After that, display a normal dialog if you need one again. IMO this is the best solution!

Comment: Yeah that's possible. I think the key was to create a var for AlertDialog and the PositiveButton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
        builder.setTitle("What's your question?");
    
        // Set up the input
        final EditText input = new EditText(v.getContext());
        // Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        builder.setView(input);
        input.setText("test test");
        input.setTextSize(15);
    
        // Set up the buttons
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Disable the button to prevent further clicks
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = (AlertDialog) dialog;
            alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
            alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setText("Loading...");
    
            m_text = input.getText().toString();
    
            // Simulate a 10s delay for downloading the image (Replace this with your actual download code)
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                // After the download is complete, update the button text and enable it
                alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setText("OK");
                alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(true);
    
                // Add code here to show the downloaded image on the main page
              }
            }, 10000); // Simulated 10s delay, replace with your actual download time
          }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
          }
        });
    
        builder.show();
      }
    });
```